# Linux no audio at all

Tags: audio

I am not able to hear any sound from my linux since yesterday (while on windows it works, so the audio card is fine). I tried to fix it but nothing worked. Here is some information:

```
$  inxi -A
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
       driver: snd_hda_intel
Card-2 Intel 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64

$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: laptop Kernel: 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 
4.9.2) Desktop: Xfce 4.12.2 (Gtk 2.24.25)
Distro: MX-16_x64 Metamorphosis 12 December 2016
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV730/M96 [Mobility 
         Radeon HD 4650/5165] bus-ID: 01:00.0
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio 
[Radeon HD 4000 series]
       driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
       Card-2 Intel 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller driver: 
       snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

pulseaudio reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio;
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
Reboot
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

As you can see, when I play a video with VLC (the audio output is the hdmi), volume control (pavucontrol) seems to recognize the audio:
[image: screenshot]

The HDMI port is the only available!
If in VLC i switch to build-in then even volume control is mute. The same on youtube.

I need a little help! Thank you.

Comment: It is probably driver problem. Try live booting the same distro and check if audio works. If still it doesn't work then boot some other distro

Comment: With a live distro it works :s

Comment: Reinstall the OS again then maybe something broke the driver